# why vector<double> accepts initializer_list with integer elements?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    // case I: uniform initialization
    //
    int ii = 100;
    // Error: cannot be narrowed from type 'int' to 'double' 
    // in initializer list
    //
    double dd{ ii };

    // case II: initializer_list
    //
    std::vector<double> vecDouble{ 1, 2.2 }; // fine!

    // case III: initializer_list
    //
    std::vector<int> vi = { 1, 2.3 }; // error: double to int narrowing

    // case IV: intializer_list
    // cannot be narrowed from type 'int' to 'double'
    //
    std::vector<double> vecD2{ ii, 2.2 }; // Error
}
```

Why there is inconsistency here where caseI doesn't accept int to double conversion but caseII allows the conversion.

Comment: There's no inconsistency.  `1` isn't an `int` it's an int-literal.  Replace it with `ii` and you'll see the same error as with the `double` case.

Comment: @MilesBudnek, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Long story short, this works because converting from a *constant expression* `int` to `double` is *not* a narrowing conversion. In other words, this works for the same reason why the following code works:

```
double x { 1 };
```

The compiler is required to construct `std::initializer_list<E>` for curly brace initialization. It knows the type of `E` to be `double`, because you are initializing a `std::vector<double>`. This is described in details in section 8.5.4 of the C++11 standard.

Here is an example from section 8.5.4.3:

> ```
> struct S {
>     S(std::initializer_list<double>); // #1
>     S(const std::string&); // #2
>     // ...
> };
> const S& r1 = { 1, 2, 3.0 }; // OK: invoke #1
> ```

The same section defines narrowing conversion as follows:

> A narrowing conversion is an implicit conversion

> - from a floating-point type to an integer type, or
> - from long double to double or float, or from double to float, except where the source is a constant expression and the actual value after conversion is within the range of values that can be represented
>   (even if it cannot be represented exactly), or
> - from an integer type or unscoped enumeration type to a floating-point type, except where the source is a constant expression and the actual value after conversion will fit into the target type and will produce the original value when converted back to the original type, or
> - from an integer type or unscoped enumeration type to an integer type that cannot represent all the values of the original type, except where the source is a constant expression whose value after integral promotions will fit into the target type.

The two examples with `ii` fall into the third category, i.e. conversion from `int` to `double` when the source is *not* a constant expression.

Comment: This answers why `std::vector<double> vecDouble{ 1, 2.2 };` works, but not why `std::vector<double> vecD2{ ii, 2.2 };` doesn't work.

Comment: @MilesBudnek Now it does :-)

Comment: "converting from int to double is not a narrowing conversion". It is as much a narrowing conversion as converting int to short.

Comment: @T.C. How so?  There are no 32 bit int values that cannot be perfectly represented as an IEEE double...

Comment: @Yakk "narrowing" as defined by the standard.